# On Windows 7, how can I identify any folders that contain files that have not been updated in x years?

Tags: windows, dir

On Windows 7, how can I identify any folders that contain files that have not been updated in x years? I would like to clean up unused files/folders on network drives. Initially, I just need a list of "old" folders / directories to be reviewed by others to ok deletion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Download [Free Commander](http://www.freecommander.com/)
- Run it and manoeuvre to the directory which you wish to search
- Press Alt + F7 for search
- Choose the Timestamp/Size/Attr tab and select start & end dates (start X years ago & end today)
- Q.E.D